# Multiplicatively closed set of matrices containing $A$ such that $X\ \mapsto\ AXA^3$ is surjective contains the identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $n\geq 2$ and let $U$ be a set of $n\times n$-matrices, such that

1) $\forall X,Y \in U:\ XY \in U$,

2) $\exists A \in U$ such that $f: U \longrightarrow U:\ X\ \longmapsto AXA^3 $ is surjective.

Show that $I_n \in U$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

I believe this to be false, but I was not able to find a counterexample.I tried setting, for example $AXA^3 = A^3$ and thus $A^3 = AXAXA^3 =\ldots= (AX)^n A^3$ and other tricks like that, but to no avail.

Edit: I think I have a counterexample: If $U$ consists only of $\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$, this satisfies the rules. Also $U = \left\{\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0),\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)\right\}$ with $A = \operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$ satisfies the rules. Are these counterexamples right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have indeed found a whole collection of counterexamples. It is easy to verify that for $n=2$, setting 
$$X:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
the singleton set $U:=\{X\}$ is a counterexample. Indeed $X^2=X\in U$ and the map
$$f:\ U\ \longrightarrow\ U:\ X\ \longmapsto\ X\cdot X\cdot X^3=X^5=X,$$
is surjective. But clearly $I_2\notin U$.

However, if $A$ is required to be *invertible* then the statement is true: Let $X\in U$ be such that $f(X)=A^4$, i.e. such that $AXA^3=A^4$. Because $A$ is invertible it follows that $X=I$ and hence that  $I\in U$.